# tor-controller Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Would a separate tag for Tor Controller be appropriate?  I've only posted a couple of questions, but both were very much completely in the realm of Tor Controller (don't have the 150 rep to create the tag).

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to create this tag at the moment. When you search for question which contain the word "[control](https://tor.stackexchange.com/search?q=control%20is%3Aquestion)", there are only a few which really deal with the control specification. Right the tag [protocol](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol) seems to be a better fit. I added also this tag to your questions.